# How to install apropriate driver in Linux Mint via Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, display-driver

I have a slight problem with Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon installed on Virtual Box 6.0.14, which is hosted on Windows 10. Everytime I boot into VM I get a driver error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to sort it out? I tried different solutions found on the internet, including Guest Additions reinstall, but no success. In VM settings I have 3D acceleration enabled, 256MB of video memory and VMSVGA controller set.

Best regards, Dan.